# Is free expansion of an ideal gas necessarily adiabatic?

Tags: thermodynamics

I wanted to know if the term "free expansion" automatically implies an  adiabatic  vessel.Is it possible that there can be a transfer of heat in the free expansion of an ideal gas (as the term seems to imply to me that only external pressure is zero)?
Can we have something like Q=∆U

Comment: Of course there can and even must be transfer, process can be only approximately adiabatic.